# Markup Language Parser in C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm new to C++ and decided to write a parser for a markup language.  I chose org-mode because it seemed relatively straightforward.

**parsertest.cpp**

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using json = nlohmann::json;

struct Flags {
  int v_nh{1}; // number of headings
  bool f_nh{false};
  bool f_p{false}; // print all
  std::string v_dir{""};
  bool f_dir{false};  // traverse directory
  bool f_json{false}; // json output
} f;

struct RegexStrings {
  std::smatch s;

  const std::regex headings_h{R"(^\** )"};
  const std::regex quote_g{R"(^\#\+begin_quote$)"};
  const std::regex quote_h{R"(^\#\+end_quote$)"};
  const std::regex src_f{R"(^\#\+begin_src .*)"};
  const std::regex src_g{R"(^\#\+begin_src)"};
  const std::regex src_h{R"(^\#\+end_src$)"};
  const std::regex url_h{R"(^https?:\/\/[[:graph:]]+)"};
  const std::regex timestamp_h{R"(^\[\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\]$)"};
} rs;

std::vector<std::string> getOrgFilesRecursively(std::string path) {
  std::vector<std::string> flist{""};
  fs::path cpath{path};
  for (const auto &p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(cpath)) {
    if (!fs::is_directory(p)) {
      std::string pp = p.path();
      // pp.substr(1, -1); // not required, really.
      if (pp.substr(pp.length() - 3) == "org") {
        flist.emplace_back(pp);
      }
    }
  }
  return flist;
}

std::vector<std::string> parseArgs(int a, char *b[]) {
  if (strcmp(b[1], "-help") == 0) {
    std::cout << "Org-Mode parser\n"
              << "-nh: Number of Headings\n"
              << "-p: Print object stack\n"
              << "-d: Recurse directory\n"
              << "-j: dump json\n";
    exit(0);
  }
  std::vector<std::string> flist{""};
  for (int i = 1; i < a; i++) {
    if (b[i][0] != '-') {
      auto carg = std::string(b[i]);
      fs::path cpath{carg};
      if (carg.substr(carg.length() - 3) == "org") {
        if (!fs::exists(cpath)) {
          continue;
        }
        flist.emplace_back(carg);
      }
    } else {
      if (b[i][1] == 'n') {
        if (b[i][1] == 'h') {
          i++;
          auto carg = std::string(b[i]);
          f.v_nh = stoi(carg);
          f.f_nh = true;
        }
      }
      if (b[i][1] == 'p') {
        f.f_p = true;
      }
      if (b[i][1] == 'd') {
        i++;
        f.v_dir = std::string(b[i]);
        f.f_dir = true;
      }
      if (b[i][1] == 'j') {
        f.f_json = true;
      }
    }
  }
  if (f.f_dir)
    flist = getOrgFilesRecursively(f.v_dir);
  if (f.f_p && f.f_json)
    f.f_p = false; // You can view the json instead
  return flist;
}

struct ParseF {
  // 0: line number
  // 1: type
  //   -1: text
  //    0: heading
  //    1: quote open
  //    2: quote close
  //    3: src open
  //    4: src close
  //    5: url
  //    6: timestamp
  // 2: data
  // 3: data
  // 4: filename
  std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, std::string, int, std::string>> cdb{};

  std::string cline{""};
  std::string cfilename{""};
  int clnum{0};

  json jo;

  void printAll();
  void printLastInsert();

  void collateAll(int, std::string, int);

  bool checkForHeadings();
  bool checkForQUOTE();
  bool checkForSRC();
  bool checkForURL();
  bool checkForTIMESTAMP();
};

void ParseF::printAll() {
  std::cout << "line, type, data, data, filename\n";
  for (auto &i : cdb) {
    std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << ", " << std::get<1>(i) << ", "
              << std::get<2>(i) << ", " << std::get<3>(i) << ", "
              << std::get<4>(i) << "\n";
  }
}

void ParseF::printLastInsert() {
  auto ctup = cdb.back();
  std::cout << std::get<0>(ctup) << ", " << std::get<1>(ctup) << ", "
            << std::get<2>(ctup) << ", " << std::get<3>(ctup) << ", "
            << std::get<4>(ctup) << "\n";
}

void ParseF::collateAll(int ttype, std::string sdata, int idata) {
  if (f.f_json) {
    jo[cfilename][std::to_string(clnum)][std::to_string(ttype)][sdata];
    jo[cfilename][std::to_string(clnum)][std::to_string(ttype)]
      [std::to_string(idata)];
  } else {
    cdb.emplace_back(std::make_tuple(clnum, ttype, sdata, idata, cfilename));
  }
}

bool ParseF::checkForHeadings() {
  // does not need full regexes
  if (std::regex_search(cline, rs.s, rs.headings_h)) {
    collateAll(0, cline.substr(rs.s.length()), rs.s.length() - 1);
    return true;
  } else
    return false;
}

bool ParseF::checkForQUOTE() {
  if (std::regex_search(cline, rs.s, rs.quote_g)) {
    collateAll(1, "\0", -1);
    return true;
  } else if (std::regex_search(cline, rs.s, rs.quote_h)) {
    collateAll(2, "\0", -1);
    return true;
  } else
    return false;
}

bool ParseF::checkForSRC() {
  if (std::regex_search(cline, rs.s, rs.src_g)) {
    int ss = rs.s.length() + 1;
    if (std::regex_search(cline, rs.s, rs.src_f)) {
      collateAll(3, cline.substr(ss), -1);
    } else {
      collateAll(3, "\0", -1);
    }
    return true;
  } else if (std::regex_search(cline, rs.s, rs.src_h)) {
    collateAll(4, "\0", -1);
    return true;
  } else
    return false;
}

bool ParseF::checkForURL() {
  if (std::regex_search(cline, rs.s, rs.url_h)) {
    collateAll(5, "\0", -1);
    return true;
  } else
    return false;
}

bool ParseF::checkForTIMESTAMP() {
  if (std::regex_search(cline, rs.s, rs.timestamp_h)) {
    collateAll(6, "\0", -1);
    return true;
  } else
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::vector<std::string> flist = parseArgs(argc, argv);
  ParseF x;
  for (int i = 1; i < flist.size(); i++) {
    std::ifstream cfile{flist.at(i)};
    std::string cline{""};
    int clnum{0};
    x.cfilename = flist.at(i);
    while (std::getline(cfile, cline) && f.v_nh > 0) {
      x.cline = cline;
      x.clnum = clnum;
      if (x.checkForHeadings()) {
        if (f.f_nh)
          f.v_nh--;
      } else if (x.checkForQUOTE()) {

      } else if (x.checkForSRC()) {

      } else if (x.checkForURL()) {

      } else if (x.checkForTIMESTAMP()) {

      } else {
        x.collateAll(-1, cline, -1);
      }
      clnum++;
    }
    cfile.close();
  }

  if (f.f_p)
    x.printAll();

  if (f.f_json) {
    std::ofstream o("dump.json");
    o << std::setw(4) << x.jo
      << std::endl; // setw is overloaded to set pretty printing
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Sample org-mode files:

https://github.com/emacs-straight/org-mode/raw/main/doc/org-manual.org

https://github.com/emacs-straight/org-mode/raw/main/doc/org-guide.org

**compile:** (requires https://github.com/nlohmann/json)

```
g++ parsertest.cpp -std=c++17 -Lnlohmann/json -o parsertest
```

**usage:**

```
./parsertest -p file.org
```

```bsh
~/C++/orgparser$ time ./parsertest -d ~/bigorgdirectory/ -j

real    0m39.509s
user    0m38.902s
sys 0m0.496s
~/C++/orgparser$ fd -t f -e org . ~/bigorgdirectory/ -x wc -l | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
666342
~/C++/orgparser$ du -sh ~/bigorgdirectory/
86M /home/user/bigorgdirectory
```

Right now, this parses ~2 MB per second.  I suppose that is slow.  How can I speed it up?  Should I not use regular expressions?  Please point out any noob-tier mistakes I might have made.

Comment: [Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: Thank you, that was a good blog post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Naming things

The first thing that strikes me about your code is that you have a lot of variable and struct names that are unnecessarily abbreviated. While it saves some typing in the beginning, it makes it harder for others to read your code, including your future self in just half a year, because you will have forgotten what exactly every abbreviation meant.

While overly long names are not helpful either, here are some general rules of thumb:

- Don't use one-character names unless it has a very commonly used meaning, like `i` for an integer index, or `x`/`y`/`z` for coordinates.
- Short names are OK if they are completely self-explanatory or if their meaning is clear from the immediate context.
- Some abbreviations are fine if they are commonly used, like `str` to denote a string, `namespace fs` is another one that is fine.

If I just look at some of the names in your code, I have questions like:

- `ParseF`: is this a parser? Or does it hold parsing results? What does the `F` mean?
- `cdb`, is that a database of something? If so, what is the `c`?
- `jo`, if I didn't see that it's type is `json` I would have no clue that this probably means "**J**SON **o**bject", although even that is not very helpful.

Your function names are all helpfully descriptive.

## Avoid using global variables

Global variables can sometimes be necessary, but they are problematic in larger projects and in libraries, as they pollute the global namespace. There are several ways to avoid these issues:

1. Make them `static`, so they will only be visible to the source file they are in, and not pollute the global namespace of symbols during linking.
2. Even better, if they are only used inside one `class` or `struct`, move them into that `class`/`struct`. If they are only used within one function, move them into that function.
3. If they are shared between classes/functions, you might declare them in one and pass them to the other via function arguments.

`rs` is only used within member functions of `ParseF`, so just make it a member variable of `ParseF`.

`f` is mostly used in `parseArgs()` and `main()`, and `f.f_json` is used inside `ParseF::collateAll()`. I would add a member variable `flist` to `Flags`, so `parseArgs()` can return both the parsed flags and the list of files in the return value. I would also add a `f_json` member variable to `ParseF`, and add a constructor that sets that variable. This way, after parsing the command line options, `main()` can pass the value of `f.f_json` to `x`.

## Prefer creating a new `struct` instead of a `tuple` type

`cdb` is a vector of `std::tuple<int, int, std::string, int, std::string>`. When I look at that type, it basically tells me nothing except it's something that consists of three integers and two strings. What does each of the components mean? Will you remember the correct order of things? While `std::tuple` and `std::pair` have their uses, it's much better to instead define a `struct` where possible, as a `struct` will have a name of itself, and each of the components of that `struct` will have a name, thereby documenting itself. You also don't have to bother with `std::make_tuple` and `std::get`. So:

```
struct Entry {
    int line_number;
    int type;
    std::string string_data;
    int int_data; // or string_length?
    std::string filename;
};

std::vector<Entry> cdb;
```

To print entries, you now write:

```
for (const auto &entry: cdb) {
    std::cout << entry.line_number << ", " << entry.type << ", " << ...;
}
```

And to add a new one:

```
cdb.emplace_back(clnum, ttype, sdata, idata, cfilename);
```

## Restructure the code

`ParseF` has some functions that help parse a single line, but the main parsing loop is in `main()`. It would be much nicer to have a `parseFile()` member function in `ParseF` (ooh, was that the `F` in the name of that struct?).

```
void ParseF::parseFile(const std::string &filename) {
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(file, line) && ...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This moves a lot of the parsing responsibilities out of `main()`, it now just has to loop over the filenames:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    for (const auto &filename: flist) {
        x.parseFile(filename);
    }
    ...
}
```

Another benefit is that all the helper functions (`collateAll()`, `checkFor*()`) can now be made `private`.

## Error handling

Your code ignores all errors. Consider that some files passed on the command line might not exist, or you don't have permissions to read, or there is a read error halfway reading the file. The user might have passed incorrect flags. Some files might not be valid org-mode files. The problem with ignoring these issues is that the program will just happily run without printing any warning and returning with an exit code of zero, and no-one is the wiser that the resulting dump.json file contains incorrect data.

Make sure you check that files are read correctly by checking that `cfile.eof() == true` after the `while`-loop that reads in all the lines. Check that the output was written correctly by calling `o.close()` and then checking that `o.good() == true`. If anything is wrong, write an error message to `std::cerr` and make sure you return a non-zero exit code, preferrably [`EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status).

Preferrably, you should also validate that the input files are correct.

## Increasing performance

> Right now, this parses ~2 MB per second. I suppose that is slow. How can I speed it up? Should I not use regular expressions?

Martin York is correct here. Regular expressions are a useful tool, but beware of using the wrong tool for a given problem. Regular expressions *can* be fast, but usually only when they can process a large amount of data at a time. If you process only a line at a time, have to check this against 8 different regular expressions, and only one of them can match succesfully at a time anyway, you are going to waste a lot of CPU time.

In your case, I think the quickest is to create a hand-written decision tree to classify each line. A lot can be learned from just looking at the first character:

- If it starts with `*`, it's a heading
- If it starts with `#`, it's a begin or end clause
- If it starts with `h`, it might be a URL
- If it starts with a digit, it might be a timestamp.

You could write this as a series of `if`-statements, or perhaps also using a `switch`-statement.

Comment: Thank you, your advice was very useful.  I improved my program, and it's much more readable (at least to me, anyway) and ~65x faster.  I have not (yet) implemented everything, but I plan to.
Here's what I have right now:
https://gist.github.com/t-e-r-m/626b94c7f8e29eece5e34bafe1c0232c
Thanks again!

Comment: Great! Feel free to post your revised code as a new question on CodeReview.

Answer (score 0):

You can get significant performance boosts by having the compiler optimize your code. Try -O 3 (please check the g++ man page for the compiler flags).

Comment: While your answer is correct as far as it goes, it doesn't make any insightful observations about the code, which is what we really do here on Code Review. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).